# PHP Construct with Static Variable

Tags: php, oop, constructor, static

I am racking my brain here. Just when I think I am understanding something, I am proven wrong.

My question involves using a static method, static variable, and the __construct magic method. Let's look at this example

```
<?php

class DummyStatic
{
    public static $variable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$variable = 'Dummy Text';
    }

    public static function text()
    {
        return self::$variable;
    }   

}

$dummyText = DummyStatic::text();

?>
```

I was under the assumption that when I call `DummyStatic::text();` that it would return `Dummy Text`.

I am using an MVC in another project where something like this is being done with success but why it doesn't work being stand alone is driving me crazy.

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't initialize static variables in the constructor. The constructor function is for initializing new objects, a static property should be available on the class (without having called any constructor).

Comment: @CarlGroner Thanks for the comment. But I do not see why you are saying `Don't initialize static variables in the constructor`...It seems that it could be very beneficial at times. Could you explain?

Comment: I guess it's beneficial if you don't want the value to be available before an object of the class is created but I cant imagine many cases for that. Even if you want the constructor to modify the value, an explicit initial value would be better IMO.

Comment: @CarlGroner I see your point. I am happy to at least know how to use it if the need arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not return "Dummy Text" because the constructor was never executed. The constructor is only executed on a new instance of the class.

```
$foo =  new DummyStatic();
echo DummyStatic::text();
```

This would, however, print out "Dummy Text"

Comment: Just the right simplified answer I needed. Thank you Stah!